# How to only select rows that have not been soft deleted in a SQL Query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, duplicates, soft-delete

I am trying to deduplicate my companies database of companies.

The database administrator left for a new position and has not been replaced.
So I as the IT support guy have been roped into babysitting it for the time being.

I am having trouble with this query in MS Access.

```
SELECT dbo_Companies.PostCode, 
dbo_Companies.Phone, 
dbo_Companies.CpyID, 
dbo_Companies.Name, 
dbo_Companies.Building, 
dbo_Companies.Street, 
dbo_Companies.City, 
dbo_Companies.Deleted
FROM dbo_Companies
WHERE (((dbo_Companies.PostCode) In (SELECT [PostCode] FROM [dbo_Companies] 
As Tmp GROUP BY [PostCode],[Phone] 
HAVING Count(*)>=2  And [Phone] = [dbo_Companies].[Phone])) 
AND ((dbo_Companies.Deleted)=False))
ORDER BY dbo_Companies.PostCode, dbo_Companies.Phone;
```

It works mostly, the problem I am having is that it searches for records in which there are more than 2 instances of a post code and phone number, which is what I want.

However I want it to not search through any soft deleted records, it does search for soft deleted records but then filters them out of the table it produces.

| PostCode | Phone | CpyID | Name | Building | Street | City | Deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB12 4AX | 1224404407 | 132931 | joe bloggs | example text | street 1 | Aberdeen | FALSE |
| AB12 4AX | 1224404407 | 99338 | joe bloggs co | example text | street 1 | Aberdeen | TRUE |

So I end up with loads of records which fit the criteria but only because of soft deleted records.

Is there any way to make it only match records by postcode and phone that are non soft deleted records, rather then just filtering them out of the resulting table.

Thank you to anyone in advanced.

---

Running the query you suggested johey, I'm still encountering the same results. It outputs some records which fit my criteria and some single ones that don't.

| PostCode | Phone | CpyID | Name | Building | Street | City | Deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BB4 4PW | 01706223999 | 26855 | DRIVER TRETT (Driver Group Plc) | Driver House 4 St Crispin Way | Haslingden | Rossendale | FALSE |
| BB4 4PW | 01706223999 | 210016 | Driver Trett | Driver House 4 | 4 St Crispin Way | Rossendale | FALSE |
| BB4 7PA | 01706219444 | 131303 | Jacobson Group |  |  | Rossendale | FALSE |

Jacobson Group should not be showing because the only record which matches on postcode and phone number has been soft deleted as shown below.

| PostCode | Phone | CpyID | Name | Building | Street | City | Deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BB4 7PA | 01706219444 | 85544 | JACOBSON D& SONS LTD |  | Bacop Road | Rossendale | True |

Comment: Strange query! What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Select 2 or more records which have matching phone numbers and postcodes but are not soft deleted records. At the moment it selects 2 or more records (regardless of whether or not it is soft deleted) which have matching phone numbers and postcodes then filters out the soft deleted ones in the resulting table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, then try this one:

```
SELECT dbo_Companies.PostCode, 
  C.Phone, 
  C.CpyID, 
  C.Name, 
  C.Building, 
  C.Street, 
  C.City, 
  C.Deleted
FROM dbo_Companies AS C
WHERE C.PostCode In (
    SELECT PostCode
    FROM [dbo_Companies] As CTMP
    WHERE CTMP.Phone = C.Phone
    AND CTMP.Deleted=False
    GROUP BY CTMP.PostCode, CTMP.Phone
    HAVING Count(*)>=2  
)
AND C.Deleted=False
ORDER BY C.PostCode, C.Phone;
```

However, the logic of that PostCode condition doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to achieve with that?
Why does it filter companies based on the post code count? And why is the Phone relevant in that condition?

Comment: +1 I also think this should work because Where clause is processed before Having so it'll filter out the deleted records before applying the logic to return count > 2. Ref for order of operations in sql https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-order-of-operations/

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question, but as I said in my question, I'm the IT guy who got roped into taking care of the database. I'm really not well versed in SQL at all.
What is an outer query and how would I go about adding an addition where condition in it? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just as in my answer: cf. the second last line (WHERE dbo_Companies.Deleted=False).

Comment: Sorry, I think I've made a mistake: in your original query the Deleted=False condition actually is already correctly placed. The amount of (unneeded) parentheses are making the query a bit hard to read. I'll update my post.

Comment: I've updated the question with some results from query you posted. Still encountering the same issue unfortunately. Though I really do appreciate the time you've spent helping me.

Comment: I never use Access, but I know it has some quirks. Can you try using Deleted<>True instead of Deleted=False ?

Comment: I've tried doing <>True instead, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: That's weird. Can you just try SELECT * FROM dbo_Companies
WHERE dbo_Companies.Deleted=False just to check if that works as intended?

Comment: That seems to work fine. I'm not sure why it applies it after matching the postcode and phone number and won't apply it before.

Comment: Would a subquery work? something like "SELECT dbo_Companies.PostCode = (SELECT PostCode 
                    FROM dbo_Companies
                   WHERE Deleted=0)"

Comment: I work for a customer relations management company, basically we have a bunch of clients which have duplicate records. We need records that have the same address and phone number to be deduplicated so that we have only one record for that company. I'm trying to run a query which will grab the duplicate records so I can identify them and delete the one of the records.

Comment: It works, It works beautifully. Thank you so much, you have no idea how much weight has been lifted off my shoulders with that working. I really can't thank you enough for spending your time helping me with this. You are the GOAT.

Comment: Great! You're welcome! (PS: your explanation about the duplicate records really clarifies the goal of that query; would have been good to know! ;-)